# JSON deserialize Exception System.LimitException: Apex heap size too large: 6127921

Tags: json

I have a JSON too large to be deserialize, and I'm getting the Exception System.LimitException: Apex heap size too large: 6127921.

I used groupeRame = (groupeRame) JSON.deserialize(jsonRequest, groupeRame.class), where groupeRame.class is a inner class wrapper.

I tried JSON2Apex but it did not work too.

Would anyone have an idea to correct this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: defer the work to a queueable (limit will be 12MB and 60sec CPU)

Comment: Thanks how to process ?

Answer (score 2):

**Transaction receiving the JSON (CPU limit = 10 sec, Heap = 6MB)**

*for example, an APEX REST service that has a method annotated `@HttpPost`*

```
System.enqueueJob(new MyQueueable(jsonRequest));
```

**Queueable outer (or inner) class (CPU limit = 60 sec, Heap = 12MB)**

```
public class MyQueueable implements System.Queueable {

  String jsonBody;
  public MyQueueable(String jsonBody) {this.jsonBody = jsonBody;}

  public execute(QueueableContext qc) {

    MyApexType myType = (MyApexType) Json.deserialize(this.jsonBody,MyApexType.class);
    ... do something with deserialized myType
  }
}
```

Comment: Can use it in     @HttpPost
    webservice static Retour importGestionPrioriteClient() {
?

Comment: @SylvainCoppin - edited my answer

Comment: It's work but i can't have the return of the request, because execute is asynchronous.

Comment: Well, you need to either get the poster to reduce the size of the Json or change the interface such that the reply is async.  The SFDC limit is a hard limit.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think its possible with apex as synchronous limit is 6mb. Instead can you try returning to front end (Lightning Aura component/LWC or page) and process it by using `JSON.parse(jsonRequest)`

However, if this is used just for database operations and not showing anything on UI, then put this logic in future or queueable methods. Async apex limits for heap is 12mb.

Comment: It is a webservice and I try to deserialyse the request body response :

        String jsonRequest = RestContext.request.requestBody.toString();
            groupeRame = (groupeRame) JSON.deserialize(jsonRequest, groupeRame.class);

Comment: are you saving anything to database in salesforce OR are you displaying in UI?

Comment: After trying to deserialyze , yes I insert the data into an sObject

Comment: And for information when I used JSON2Apex  I have a CPU limit exceeded Exception